# How do i make a list <li> display freely instead of down?

Tags: hyperlink

On my site hiphopcanvass.com I added the blogroll in the footer.  I want the height to be a certain size, right now its on auto. If the content of the blogroll gets to that height then it will display on the other side until its fully across. What i want can be seen in the image below.

[image]

Comment: This isn't really a WordPress question, per se. It's a general CSS question.

Comment: do i go somewhere else to ask that??

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this in the footer of my site to display my categories (although I'm only displaying them in two short columns).

[image: Horizontal Categories]

To do this, I'm using the following CSS to manipulate the list elements:

`#footer ul li.footercolumn{float: left; display: block; width: 210px; margin-right: 20px;}`

`#footer  ul li.footercolumn ul li { float: left; width: 50%; margin-bottom:10px; }`

(This will have to be customized to fit your application of course).

There are several ways to create multiple columns using CSS, I'd recommend checking out [CSS Wizardry's](http://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/) and [A List Apart's](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/) articles on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

You need to float the `<li>` left and change the height of the footerwidget from auto to 50px
[image]